# Height of the division in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I am trying out forms in HTML.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmrLjdy7/)

For the div #status, the CSS rules are-

```
#status{
  margin:auto; 
  width:50%;  
  border:2px solid red; 
  background:white;
  height:40%;
}
```

But I cannot understand why the height of divison does not get altered by height rule in the CSS. More over If I try out-

```
#status{
  margin:auto; 
  width:50%;  
  border:2px solid red; 
  background:white;
  height:40px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmrLjdy7/1/)

This leaves the text on the bottom while div is placed at some random place.
Could some help with placing this division below E-mail ID field so that text appears inside it?

Also, which rule in my CSS is responsible for this positioning of div.

Comment: if the div contains the content then it holds the height if the div content length is less than 40% it will set to the height of the content so you have to change the `height to min-height`

Comment: @JohnAnkanna I have tried that https://jsfiddle.net/zmrLjdy7/2/.. No change! I do not understand why this text is displaying at the bottom of the division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inserting the `div` under elements that are floating. You need to add `clear: both` to your `#status` CSS rules:

```
#status {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: white;
  height: 40%; /* or 40px, which will look slightly different. Your choice. */
  clear: both;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3sttek0/)